Strain Gauge NFC
My goal is to put a strain gauge to work in conjunction with an NFC or any wireless energy and data transfer system.
Well, I've been looking at some nfc examples but they all work by returning pre-recorded data. Would it be possible to return data from a sensor using this technology?
Strain gauges use low current to work, so is it possible to use an NFC to connect them?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your premise that adequate strain gauge excitation power is within the range available from conventional NFC devices might need re-examination.


so is it possible to use an NFC to connect them?

Yes.
You need to look in better places. The major producers of NFC chips have development kits with which you can build NFC sensors; an NFC devices is always just a microcontroller on a coil; it just happens that some of them are only built to return saved data.
So, better research with the chip vendors rather than some, honestly, pretty questionably looking consumer sales websites (hint: serious electronic distributors don't do "5 star review systems"; that makes no sense for components).
